# I dont know how to pull out image ID from echoed data

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, pdo

So let me explain from the start :

```
     <?


$images_query = "SELECT * FROM `tag` ";
    $images = mysqli_query($conn, $images_query); ?>

    <div class="col-md-4 thumb panel panel-default " style="margin-bottom:5px;margin-top:5px border-style: solid;
        border-color: black;"> 

              <a title="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" class="fancybox" href="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" alt="" > <img title="1st title" style="margin-top:12px;" src="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" alt="" ></a> 


                    <div class="panel-heading" style="min-height:48px;">

                  <div class="col-md-4" data-href="http://etronhosting.com/brain/<? echo $test;?>"> <img class="imgshare2" src="images/dl.png" style="max-height:40px;"></img>

   <form method="post">
             <input type="submit" value="add" name="fav"/>
             </form>
                 <? 
                 if(isset($_POST['fav'])){
                 $sq = "INSERT INTO `favourites`  (`name`)
                          SELECT `name` from `tag`";
                 $insert=mysqli_query($conn,$sq );}?>

                  </div>
                 <div class="fb-share-button col-md-4" data-href="http://etronhosting.com/brain/<? echo $row['name'];?>" data-layout="button_count"> </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4"> 


                 </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
```

So from the first div,it echoes out `name` from table `tag`-So it Displays every image iv stored into `tag` table.
In div tag with "fb share" class is as u guess facebook share button. 
But the problem is in the form.Basicly what i am trying to do is add a "Add to favourites button" where when user clicks on it,it copies pucture name (path) to the favourites table.And probobly session id with it.Then on the favourites.php i could echo out every image with current sesson_id.
Iv tryed many things,but mostly they insert only the name of the first picture and thats it.
Does anyone have idea how to make this work ? Or is ther e any other better method to make "add to favourites" ?

Comment: your code favorites EVERYTHING in your db, which is rather pointless. you need to embed the ID of whatever you're favoriting in that form as a hidden field. e.g. `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id_you_need" />`, then you pull out that id value and use it in your query: `insert into favs (userid, id) values($userid, $id)`

Comment: @MarcB Thats mie main problem,how do i pull it out ?`$id_i_need= <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>" />` Like that ?

Comment: you don't "pull it out" - you already have it. just add it to your db query that generates the list in the first place.

Comment: @MarcB Yeah u hit right on spot,tnx a lot! I dont know how to mark your comment as answer though.